# NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget any object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

I'm currently using

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```

to cancel my performSelector for `doneMoving:`. This causes an issue because I have other performSelectors running that I *do not* want to cancel. The solution would be to use

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doneMoving:) object:objectIDontKnow];
```

but I don't know the object that was passed with the original performSelector. I want to be able to cancel all `doneMoving:` requests, no matter what object was passed, while still maintaining my other scheduled methods. Thanks!

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using perform selector. Have you thought about using an operation queue? what is your code doing?

Answer (score -1):

try to rewrite your code in a different way, so you don't pass the object

```
- (void)moveObject {

    [self.objectToMove doSmth];

}

- (void)performMoveObjectInFuture:(id)moveObject {

    self.objectToMove = moveObject;
    [self performSelector:@selector(moveObject) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];

}
```